# $\pi$ and $e$ as coded trajectories

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, pi

*Question about the number $\pi$ and $e$ and their unpredictability.*

We know that $\pi=3.141592653589793238462643383279502884...$ Suppose that we are in the origin of the plane i.e. at the point $(0,0)$ and we have possibility to move according to digits of $\pi$.

Let

> > digit $1$ be code for move $[1,0]$ (*vector of translation*),
> >     2 for move $[0,1]$,
> >     3 for move $[-1,0]$,
> >     4 for move $[0,-1]$,
> >     others digits of $\pi$ to be ignored.

- Could we somehow prove that starting from the origin and  taking the
  first digit $3$ as the first command of movement, then 1, then 4 etc
  ..... we can move outside area of a circle with  any given radius
  after enough long time or there is however some boundary for our
  potential infinite movements ?
- And what about $e=2.71828182845904523536...$,   maybe for **all**
  transcendental numbers such trajectory, I suspect, is unbounded ?
  *(could we say that $e$ is in the same class of difficulty for analysis as $\pi$  or however in some lighter class?)*
- $^{Additionally}$  Could trajectories for $\pi$ and $e$ when they
  were been started at the same time (and it is a single movement for
  them in the unit time) would meet one day on 2D plane?

---

**Edit after 5 days**

If the above questions are too difficult to tackle couldn't we try to determine at least whether the difference between even and odd digits of $\pi$ or $e$ is unbounded or not.. the numbers for consideration can be also in binary format so the question would be about difference of sums of digits $1$ and digits $0$ in these numbers for approximations of $\pi$ or $e$ with $n$ digits denoted as $\pi_n$ or $e_n$.

Then difference (for $\pi$)  can be denoted as $\Delta_{oe}(\pi_n)=s_o(\pi_n)-s_e(\pi_n)$ or for binary version $\Delta_{10}(\pi_n)=s_1(\pi_n)-s_0(\pi_n)$ what is equal $2s_1(\pi_n)-n$.

So if $n$ (number of known binary digits) is increasing with the time of calculations $t$ (we can assume any relation between $n$ and $t$, also linear) the problem is equivalent to determine whether  fluctuations $s_1(\pi_n)$ over and under line $f(t)=n/2$ are bounded or not in reference to this line..

Comment: Certainly your last comment is not right, there are transcendental numbers whose digits are all 5 or 6. (Just imitate Liouville's original construction.) I think you are aiming for *normal* numbers.

Comment: @Ian Could you give example, I was unaware of it..

Comment: You should take the numbers in base 4

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number

Comment: Perhaps if we assume that pi is normal, or some similar condition. If the digits occur with random probability, then this is a random walk on a square lattice, and we can show the rms distance grows with $\sqrt{N}$

Comment: @Aurey Could be proved that for any movement there were not almost equal counter movements earlier ?-  movements are made in all directions .. what about $e$ - the same situation ?

Comment: @Noam Are somewhere available representations for $\pi$ and $e$ as the numbers in base 4 .. I have found   $\pi$=  3.02100 33312 22202 02011 22030 02031 03010 30121 20220 23200 03130 01303 10102 21000 21032 00202 02212 13303 01310 00020.., $e$ is harder to find..

Comment: @Noam We can also use base 6 ...
  $\pi$= 3.05033 00514 15124 10523 44140 53125 32110 23012 14442 00411 52525 53314 20333 13113 55351 31233 45533 41001 51543 44401 .....and to study motion in 3D......

Comment: **After two days.** Dear MSE users, is there not any sketch for a procedure how to tackle the problem?

Comment: I'd say it's unbounded but it'll be hard to prove. Here is a picture of the first 100000 points: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksucb.png

Comment: @lhf Impressive, but it's hard to find a pattern.. really unpredictable number..

Comment: @lhf If you lhd have generated this trajectory according to given by me rules (or similar) you can give this picture as the answer, complete only information what is the final distance after the first 100000 points..I'm curious also , how it would be looking also the graph for the distance as the function of number of digits..

Comment: maybe this $\pi$ trajectory is some kind of a fractal?

Comment: @Widawensen Here is 100k digits of e in base 4, is that enough? http://pastebin.com/894a98H1

Comment: @AdamWhite Probably it's enough to see regularities if they occur. We only need some program for visualization..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's unbounded but it'll be hard to prove.

Here is a picture of the trajectory of the first 100000 points and a graph of the distance to the origin for this trajectory. The largest distance is $\sqrt{45520} \approx 213$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be good to have also a graph for k=distance/number_of_steps. I hope it would be visible that is going to 0. $k\rightarrow{0}$ is of course necessary condition for existence of boundary, but not sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

It is extremely unlikely that you're going to be able to get any answer for any question of this sort.  Questions about the decimal expansions of irrational numbers are totally unconnected to anything we'd normally consider a good mathematical property of the numbers.

To illustrate how complete our lack of understanding is here, we cannot currently rule out the following statement:

> The googol-th digit in the decimal expansion of pi is a 7, and after this point *every single digit* is either a 7 or a 9.  In particular, all the other digits only appear finitely many times in the decimal expansion.

Oh, and here's another statement we also can't currently rule out:

> $\pi + e$ is a rational number.

I'm more confident that these statements are false than I am that the sun will come up in the morning, but I'll also not optimistic that either will be disproven in my lifetime.  (Note that the former statement, if true, would give answers to most of your questions that are not the expected ones.)

Comment: $\pi+e$ could be rational ? Astonishing ....and there is no method of checking it ?  The same about for example for $e^{\pi}$ ?

Comment: It's very hard, in general, to prove that a number is irrational.  I mean, look up a proof that pi is irrational some time.  Such proofs depend on particular mathematical properties of numbers like $\pi$ and $e$.  On the other hand, a number like $\pi + e$ has very few nice mathematical properties, so it'd be much harder to prove that it's irrational (assuming it is).

Comment: On the other hand, the number $e^\pi$ actually has a very nice mathematical property: namely, we have that $(e^\pi)^i = -1$.  From this Gelfond showed that $e^\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: So we more know about $e^\pi$ than $e$+$\pi$ :). Could we say that all this unpredictability is somehow connected with the theory of chaos? .. and from that  we can generate chaos from something so much regular as the circle ( what could be more regular ...)

Comment: I'm not aware of any connections to chaotic dynamics, but I'm certainly no expert on the subject.

Comment: If  $\pi$ could be generated with some simple iterative formula (so simple as possible) .... I've found http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiIterations.html

Comment: Borwein algorithm (above link) for iterative $\pi$ formula uses only powers of 2 in definition. Maybe this can be useful for testing binary representation of $\pi$ ?